# Как добавить модель в Realm?

Tags: java, android, realm

```
public class ModelAlbums{

@SerializedName("results") public ResultsBean results;

public static class ResultsBean {
    @SerializedName("opensearch:Query") public OpensearchQueryBean opensearchQuery;
    @SerializedName("opensearch:totalResults") public String opensearchtotalResults;
    @SerializedName("opensearch:startIndex") public String opensearchstartIndex;
    @SerializedName("opensearch:itemsPerPage") public String opensearchitemsPerPage;
    @SerializedName("albummatches") public AlbummatchesBean albummatches;
    @SerializedName("@attr") public attrBean attr;

    public static class OpensearchQueryBean {
        @SerializedName("#text") public String text;
        @SerializedName("role") public String role;
        @SerializedName("searchTerms") public String searchTerms;
        @SerializedName("startPage") public String startPage;
    }

    public static class AlbummatchesBean {
        @SerializedName("album") public List<AlbumBean> album;

        public static class AlbumBean implements Serializable{
            @SerializedName("name") public String name;
            @SerializedName("artist") public String artist;
            @SerializedName("url") public String url;
            @SerializedName("streamable") public String streamable;
            @SerializedName("mbid") public String mbid;
            @SerializedName("image") public List<ImageBean> image;

            public static class ImageBean {
                @SerializedName("#text") public String text;
                @SerializedName("size") public String size;
            }
        }
    }

    public static class attrBean {
        @SerializedName("for") public String forX;
    }
}
```

}

Каким образом можно добавить всю эту модель в Realm? Или такое действыие не правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой и очевидный способ:

Продублируйте каждый класс и все его поля в объекты, которые наследуются от RealmObject, все списки замените на RealmList<>. Добавьте реалм объектам пустые конструкторы и, к примеру статичные методы типа

```
OpensearchQueryBeanRealm fromJsonPojo(OpensearchQueryBean query){
    OpensearchQueryBeanRealm queryRealm = new OpensearchQueryBeanRealm();
    queryRealm.param1 = query.param1
    queryRealm.param1 = query.param2
    ......
    return queryRealm;
}
```

далее превратите полученные объекты в реалм объекты и добавьте их в реалм с помощью realm.insertOrUpdate(realmObject);